# Waiting for Context to update

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am using React Context to store the logged-in users credentials and have created a reducer/action pattern to handle the logic.  Right now, I'm able to successfully login with the proper credentials, but I also want to redirect the user to his profile with a dynamic param like so: `profile/:id`.  My problem is, I'm not sure how to access the user's id in the same function as the initial call to Context where I populate it with the user's login credentials.  So far, I have:

```
function Login(props) {
  const userContext = useContext(UserContext);

  const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState({
    username: '',
    password: ''
  });

  async function onSubmit (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const user = await userContext.loginUser(credentials); // Wait for payload...
    props.push.history(`/profile${user.id}`); // ...Then use payload (user.id) to redirect to desired endpoint
}
```

For reference, here is my `loginUser` action:

```
const loginUser = async credentials => {
  setLoading();

  const response = await axios
    .post('endpoint here', credentials)

  dispatch({
    type: LOGIN_USER, 
    payload: response.data
  })
}
```

And here is my reducer with my initial state below it:

```
export default (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case SET_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      }
    case LOGIN_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        user: action.payload,
        loading: false
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const initialState = {
  user: {},
  issues: [],
  loading: false
}
```

Hopefully, this is enough for someone to spot my shortcoming.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where's your reducer?

Comment: Just edited the initial post to include it.  Thanks for pointing that out.